# Xamarin.iOS Error - Application windows are expected to have a root view controller .... Using Static Binding

Tags: xaml, binding, xamarin.ios

I am getting this error:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are
>   expected to have a root view controller at the end of application
>   launch

Using Xamarin.iOS if I use inside my xaml file this kind of Binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:AppAlgorix.Converters"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:AppAlgorix.Resources"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="AppAlgorix.Views.LoginPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:MaskedCardConverter x:Key="cvtMaskedCard"></converters:MaskedCardConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="20">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="80">
                 <Label Text="SEJA BEM VINDO" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="None" TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Static resources:AppParameters.AppLabelColorDefault}}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I have tried this format also:

```
<Label Text="SEJA BEM VINDO" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="None" TextColor="{Binding
AppLabelColorDefault, Source={x:Static
resources:AppParameters}}"></Label>
```

My Parameters Class is this:

```
namespace AppAlgorix.Resources
{
    public static class AppParameters
    {
        public static string AppLabelColorDefault
        {
            get
            {
                var color = Parameters.ResourceManager.GetString("applabelcolordefault");
                return color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Xamarin project has Android and iOS. This approach works with Android, but do not work with iOS.

If I change my view to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:AppAlgorix.Converters"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="AppAlgorix.Views.LoginPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:MaskedCardConverter x:Key="cvtMaskedCard"></converters:MaskedCardConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="20">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="80">
                <Label Text="SEJA BEM VINDO" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="None" TextColor="Black"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

I can execute and see my view in emulator...

So, I think my problem is this Binding format...

My question is... How to resolve this error in Xamarin.iOS, without breaking Xamarin.Android ?

Comment: What is the value you get from  `Parameters.ResourceManager.GetString("applabelcolordefault");`?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I am getting my values from a resx resource file, saved on a PLC (Xamarin.forms) folder. I am getting all values without any problem. Those values are responsable for changing a lot of parameters according to the client. When I am running Android, all those values are recovered without any issue... But I can´t make the same running iOS project. As long I debug, I can see the values being took from resource file, but after that, I get the "root view" error.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Another thing I would like to add.. I am using Prism 7.1 and I dont know if it could be a reason for this problem, also.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I tried to implement the solution showned here... https://mindofai.github.io/Implementing-Localization-with-Xamarin.Forms/ But the erros still remains.

Comment: When I change the Parameters.ResourceManager.GetString("applabelcolordefault"); to ''orange" or "red", And I test it on my side, your code works well. So I wonder if the problem is there.  I would like to know what exactly the value is. And miss a root view controller exception would caused by prism, I don't know without see the code.